# Show that any object isomorphic to a product object $A\times B$ is a product of $A$ and $B$.

Tags: category-theory

This is the second part of an exercise on a book about category theory. The first one asked to show that any par of products are equal up to isomorphism.

For my attempt at proving the proposition, I used the following 2 definitions:

- An arrow $f : A \rightarrow B$ is an **isomorphism** if there is an arrow $f^{-1} : B \rightarrow A$, called the *inverse* of $f$, such that $f^{-1} \circ f = id_{A}$ and $f \circ f^{-1} = id_{B}$. The objects A and B are said to be isomorphic if there is an isomorphism between them.
- A **product** of two objects A and B is an object $A \times B$, together with two projection arrows $\pi_{1} : A \times B \rightarrow A$ and $\pi_{2} : A \times B \rightarrow B$ such that for any object C and pair of arrows $f : C \rightarrow A$ and $g : C \rightarrow B$ there si exactly one mediating arrow $\langle f , g \rangle : C \rightarrow A \times B$, such that $\pi_{1} \circ \langle f , g \rangle = f$ and $\pi_{2} \circ \langle f , g \rangle = g$.

For the proof, I started by drawing the commutative diagram of $A \times B$, the isomorphic object X and a generic object C of the product definition.

[image]

The approach I took was trying to show that $h^{-1}$ is unique.

I know that $h$ is unique because $A \times B$ is a product and we have $\pi_{1} \circ h : X \rightarrow A$ and $\pi_{2} \circ h : X \rightarrow B$. We also know that the inverse of an isomorphism is unique. Suppose there is another arrow $h^{-1'} : A \times B \rightarrow X$ that is not $h^{-1}$, then we would have $h^{-1'} \circ h : A \times B \rightarrow A \times B$ but as $A \times B$ is a product, that would mean that $h^{-1'} \circ h = id_{A \times B}$.

This is as far as I got, I would still need to show that $h \circ h^{-1'} = id_{X}$, but for that I don't have the uniqueness of the identity as the only arrow from X to X.

I don't even know if this is the right approach, my idea was to try to show that $h^{-1} \circ \langle f , g \rangle$ works for any C, but I don't know.

Comment: Are you trying to prove the isomorphism is unique, or that if they are isomorphic then it is a product? Your title asks one thing, but what you are doing seems to be the other. Note that in general there need not be a unique isomorphism between $A\times B$ and an isomorphic object $X$. The uniqueness requires that you consider the projections as well . That is, if $(X,\pi_A,\pi_B)$ is another object which is a product of $A$ and $B$, then there is a unique isomophism $h\colon X\to A\times B$ such that $\pi_A=\pi_1h$ and $\pi_B=\pi_2h$.  But in general there may be more than one isomorphism $h$

Comment: Thanks for your reply below Arturo! I was trying to show that if they are isomorphic then it is a product, and tried to do it through proving the isomorphism is unique. Now it is clear that that was not the right approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title says you are trying to prove that an object isomorphic to $A\times B$ is also a product of $A$ and $B$, with suitably defined projection maps.

But then you seem to be trying to prove that the isomorphism $h$ is somehow "unique"... But in general there need not be a unique isomorphism. For example, if $A=B$, you can $X=B\times A$ and take $h$ to be the identity, or you can take $h'$ to be the morphism $(a,b)\mapsto (b,a)$, and both will allow you to define a product structure on $B\times A$ (different product structures, but both will be a product of $A$ and $B$).

Below is a proof that if $X$ is isomorphic to $A\times B$, then via suitably defined functions $\pi_A\colon X\to A$ and $\pi_B\colon X\to B$, we have that $(X,\pi_A,\pi_B)$ is a product of $A$ and $B$, and that the original isomorphism is the only one that respects the resulting projection maps.

Let $X$ be isomorphic to $A\times B$ via $h$, $h\colon X\to A\times B$ and $h^{-1}\colon A\times B\to X$.

We let $\pi_A\colon X\to A$ be given by $\pi_A=\pi_1\circ h$, and $\pi_B\colon X\to B$ be given by $\pi_B=\pi_2\circ h$.

We want to show that $(X,\pi_A,\pi_B)$ have the universal property of the product of $A$ and $B$. To that end, let $C$ be any object, and $f\colon C\to A$ and $g\colon C\to B$ be arrows. We want to show that there exists a unique $\langle \mathfrak{f},\mathfrak{g}\rangle\colon C\to X$ such that $f=\pi_A\circ\langle \mathfrak{f},\mathfrak{g}\rangle$ and $g=\pi_B\circ\langle\mathfrak{f},\mathfrak{g}\rangle$.

**Existence.** We know there exists $\langle f,g\rangle\colon C\to A\times B$ such that $f=\pi_1\circ\langle f,g\rangle$ and $g=\pi_2\circ\langle f,g\rangle$. Define $\langle\mathfrak{f},\mathfrak{g}\rangle\colon C\to X$ by
$$\langle\mathfrak{f},\mathfrak{g}\rangle = h^{-1}\circ\langle f,g\rangle.$$
We verify that this has the desired property. We have:
$$\begin{align*}
\pi_A\circ\langle\mathfrak{f},\mathfrak{g}\rangle &= 
 (\pi_1\circ h)\circ(h^{-1}\circ\langle f,g\rangle)\\
&= \pi_1\circ \mathrm{id}_{A\times B}\circ \langle f,g\rangle\\
&= \pi_1\circ \langle f,g\rangle\\
&= f.\\
\pi_B\circ\langle\mathfrak{f},\mathfrak{g}\rangle &= (\pi_2\circ h)\circ(h^{-1}\circ \langle f,g\rangle)\\
&= \pi_2\circ \mathrm{id}_{A\times B}\circ \langle f,g\rangle\\
&= \pi_2\circ\langle f,g\rangle\\
&= g.
\end{align*}$$

**Uniqueness.** Let $\varphi\colon C\to X$ be such that $\pi_A\circ\varphi=f$ and $\pi_B\circ\varphi=g$. We want to show that $\varphi=\langle\mathfrak{f},\mathfrak{g}\rangle$.

First, note that $h\circ\varphi\colon C\to A\times B$ has
$$\begin{align*}
\pi_1\circ (h\circ\varphi) &= (\pi_1\circ h)\circ\varphi\\
&= \pi_A\circ \varphi\\
&= f\\
\pi_2\circ (h\circ\varphi) &= (\pi_2\circ h)\circ\varphi\\
&= \pi_B\circ \varphi\\
&= g.
\end{align*}$$
Since $\pi_1\circ(h\circ\varphi)=f$ and $\pi_2\circ(h\circ\varphi)=g$, the uniqueness clause of the universal property of $A\times B$ tells us that $h\circ\varphi = \langle f,g\rangle$. Therefore,
$$\varphi = h^{-1}\circ(h\circ \varphi) = h^{-1}\circ\langle f,g\rangle = \langle \mathfrak{f},\mathfrak{g}\rangle,$$
which is what we needed to prove.

Now, we have that $(X,\pi_A,\pi_B)$ and $(A\times B,\pi_1,\pi_2)$ are both products of $A$ and $B$. We know that this means that there exists a unique isomorphism $\psi\colon X\to A\times B$ such that $\pi_A=\pi_1\circ\psi$ and $\pi_B=\pi_2\circ\psi$. We show that $\psi=h$.

Indeed, we know by the Universal Property of $A\times B$ that $h$ is the unique map such that $\pi_A=\pi_1\circ h$ and $\pi_B=\pi_2\circ h$. Since $\pi_1\circ\psi=\pi_A$ and $\pi_2\circ\psi=\pi_B$, that uniqueness clause yields $\psi=h$, as desired.

Comment: Why can you affirm that $\pi_{A} \circ \varphi = f$ when showing uniqueness?

Comment: @tomasmiguez I'm not "affirming" it, I am *assuming* it. You want to show that the only function such that composed with  $\pi_A$ gives $f$ and composed with $\pi_B$ gives $g$ is $\langle\mathfrak{f},\mathfrak{g}\rangle$, so you take a function that satisfies the condition and verify it equals $\langle\mathfrak{f},\mathfrak{g}\rangle$.